# Does calling wordpress's json api affect the page view in google analytics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a page in wordpress. And I developed an android application that calls to word press's rest api , to retrieve existing pages in json format. Then I parse json and display in application.

My question is that, does my requests to rest api, affect page view in google analytics?

Regards 
Ceyhun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **NO**. 
the reason is as simple as the fact the there is no html being loaded when you make a JSON request. 
the analytics api is a javascript code that is being loaded with the page in your site but JSON pages are just pages with a string inside of them. 
so there is no real HTML being loaded > the analytics code is not activated.

If you want users to count in your analytics you should use the [Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however because I call not from other web services but rest web service, it calls directly from url.That is, url is being called however as you mentioned, no html is loaded. Is google analytics is looking to exactly this issue to affect the page view?

Comment: google analytics is a Javascript code loaded with the HTML, if the HTML is not loaded - the Javascript would not load as well.